# JQuery or Javascript code to change the font of the last character in html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, string

I know it sounds odd, but I'd like to create an html class that will change the font of the **last** character in the tagged text.

while css lets you change the fontsize, color of the **first character** of some strings, there is sadly nothing to change the font of the last character.

Is it best to use the `charAt(length-1)` in JS or is there some way in JQuery to alter the last character of the selected class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to fetch, change, and then reput the html content of your texts.

I made a fiddle to illustrate it :

http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/3maG5/

Be aware that there are risks : without greater analysis you may have problems if your paragraphs (or other texts) end with an element.

EDIT : I just see that eyurdakul made a few seconds before me a very similar answer. I think he's correct too. I let this answer as a complementary one to give a testable example. Of course, if one answer should be accepted, it's probably eyurdakul's one, he was faster :)

Answer (score 1):

give them some class for the selector, .last for example;

```
$(".last").each(function(){
     var inner = $(this).html();
     var firstPart = inner.substring(0, (inner.length-1));
     var secondPart = inner.substring((inner.length-1), inner.length);
     $(this).html(firstPart);
     $("<span/>").css("font", "Arial").html(secondPart).appendTo($(this));
});
```